# How control specific properties of GridView cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on a program that users can log in to and see any leads they got for the day.  There is one column of the gridview that needs to stand out.  The possible values are Yes or No.  I got the color and bold to change using this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SelectBroker" HeaderText="Select Broker" SortExpression="SelectBroker" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Red" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>
```

Now they are wanting this red and bold only when the value is Yes and normal text when it is No.  I inherited the site and am muddling through his old code.  I am not able to re-create it into a ListView.  Is there a way to do this?

I am not posting all the code because I don't know what you would like to see and I don't want to load tons of unnecessary code.  Let me know if you need to see any additional code.  Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        // Evaluate in the row data bound event.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Evaluate if yes then do whatever you want with the rendered text.
            if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Yes") {
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = string.Format("<span class='bold red'>{0}</span>", e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a template field, and wrap the text in a Label. Then you can add a condition to set the color and font weight.

I haven't tested it, but try something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor='<%# Eval("Value").ToString() == "YES" ? "Red" : "Black" %>'><%# Eval("Value") %></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```